# Can't get there from here should I just give up?

Tags: discussion

So I was trying to build up enough reputation to be able to do simple things like vote on questions and the like. I tried to answer some questions the best I could and now I have been answer banned. It seems really difficult for new users to get involved. Should I just shut up and go away? I have a bitter taste in my mouth for sure. I mean I had some good answers with up votes, and one bad answer that started getting voted down so I removed it but I was auto-banned by the system from answering more questions. It is really frustrating.

Comment: Also one of the questions that got downvoted the user then removed his post.. It was a question about why his Internet didn't work but he was connected to the network. Naturally I suggested to check DNS settings. I'm not really sure why that got downvoted and why the user then deleted the question. (Maybe he later figured out it was in fact DNS related?)

Comment: For that question and answer, I've undeleted your self-deleted answer.  Please check that you can now answer questions again.

Comment: Thank you for that. I will have to be very careful how to make my next answer though I don't want to get banned again. I'm afraid to make a test answer.

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to delete your answer. Especially when you are new to the site. If you had to delete the answer later on, wonder why you posted it in the first place.

Comment: If I had to delete it then yes, I should reflect on that. Although some I deleted purely because they were getting downvotes and I was trying to save points. Is it worse to delete something after a downvote than to wait for -50 or something? I suppose it could end up getting upvoted later though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can see your answers. There's no diplomatic way to deal with this so I'll give you a quick review:

- The [first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354993/how-to-remove-lines-from-the-text-file-containing-specific-words-through-termina/354997#354997) didn't answer the question. It didn't remove the whole line and it was using find for some unknown reason. You deleted this one too.
- The [second](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354858/internet-problem-repeated-disconnection-and-connection/355002#355002) was a punt. You got a down-vote and deleted it.
- The [last](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12473/file-and-directory-comparison-tool/355013#355013) didn't explain how `rsync` had anything to do with file comparison. It was deleted because it just wasn't an answer to the question.

There's a common theme here in that your answers don't really answer the questions. A code fragment here, a link there... But no cohesive reasoning.

I do understand that it might seem frustrating but there's a clear gap between what you're posting and answers that get a high number of votes. They're not getting upvotes because they're written by people with reputation, they're getting votes because they answer the question.

Perhaps spending some time suggesting improvements to otherwise full-bodied answers would be a benefit. You'll earn a couple of rep each time you have an edit approved and you'll get a better idea of what we expect.

I hope it hasn't been too harrowing.

Comment: No it's fine I need the help. What is a punt? Also the last answer was aimed at helping the user get what they wanted and they even thanked me for it.. I'm probably trying too hard to answer questions just to get the ability to vote.

Comment: In this case I meant the soccer term for kick with the front of your foot, hoping to make the ball go as far as possible, without much care or attention. A "hail Mary pass" in American football.  A guess and in that case, a guess without basis or explanation.

Comment: OK hail mary I understand. The user already deleted the question so I don't remember what it was.

Comment: @p1l0t Based on Oli's observations here, I would strongly suggest that before you post more answers that you take a look at some of the other answers done by people that have a good bit of upvotes, or were accepted as answers to a question, as those questions tend to be good examples of "good answers".  The other way to get reputation is to ask good questions, as questions that get upvoted get you reputation as well.